# Assigning Spark SQL function to variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to assign a spark SQL function to a variable.
For example:

```
    val func = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max(_)
```

Now, this is the way for doing partial functions. But when I'm doing this, I get this error:

```
  Cannot resolve overloaded method max
```

Searched online, couldn't find a solution. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note max is an overloaded function:

So either:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

scala> val func: Column => Column = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
func: org.apache.spark.sql.Column => org.apache.spark.sql.Column = <function1>
```

or

```
scala> val func: String => Column = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
func: String => org.apache.spark.sql.Column = <function1>
```

Out of interest why do you want to do this?

Comment: Thank you! Why does the annotation makes it to work? How is it related of max being overloaded function?

Comment: So there are two definitions of max, `Column => Column` and `String => Column` Defining the type tells the compiler which one we are aliasing.

Comment: Ok, I see. and what about the " _ " parameter? Doesn't it need to be provided?

Comment: It doesn't have to be provided in this case.